# Remove objects with similar values from ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I am working with ArrayList ,Here I want to remove objects with similar values from Arraylist. I tried many solutions posted over stackoverflow but something is wrong in my code due to which code is not working . I am getting list with dupliactes .

> Here is my code :

```
public class StateCityModel {

    private String id ;
    private String code ;
    private String name ;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (!(obj instanceof StateCityModel))
            return false;

        return id.equals(((StateCityModel) obj).getId());

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode();
    }
}
```

> Code add values in the ArrayList

```
    businessTypeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView , View view , int position , long l) {
 businessTypeObj = clubsList.get(position);
                    selectedBusinessTypeList.add(businessTypeObj);
                }

            }
        });
```

> Code to remove objects with similar values .

```
Set<StateCityModel> unique = new LinkedHashSet<StateCityModel>(selectedBusinessTypeList);
            selectedBusinessTypeList = new ArrayList<StateCityModel>(unique);
```

After doing above code I am getting objects with similar values in the **selectedBusinessTypeList**  .

Help me please  , I am not able to find what is wrong in the above code .

Comment: "with similar values" How similar? Please provide examples of values you expect to be deduplicated, but aren't.

Comment: @AndyTurner "with similar values" - > A list containing two objects whose fields has same values . Example : There are two objects obj1 and obj2 with fileds (id , code) and the value of id and code in both objects is same .

Comment: @AndroidDev check below answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do in this way

**Step 1: Only insert those data in arraylist which id's are not same so after that you don't need to remove duplicate elements from arraylist.**

```
businessTypeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView , View view , int position , long l) {
     businessTypeObj = clubsList.get(position);
                        selectedBusinessTypeList.add(businessTypeObj);
                    }

                }
            });
```

**Replace it by**

```
businessTypeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView , View view , int position , long l) {
                }

    StateCityModel stateCityModel = new StateCityModel();
    stateCityModel = clubsList.get(position);;

    if (!selectedBusinessTypeList.contains(stateCityModel)){
         selectedBusinessTypeList.add(stateCityModel);
    }

}
```

});

**Step2 : Remove this not needed**

```
Set<StateCityModel> unique = new LinkedHashSet<StateCityModel>(selectedBusinessTypeList);
            selectedBusinessTypeList = new ArrayList<StateCityModel>(unique);
```

Comment: Please explain why OP would want to use this approach instead of his/hers.

Comment: @AndyTurner not getting you what you want to asking actually ?

Comment: Well, you're saying "don't write that, write this", without actually saying *why* you shouldn't write that, but should write this instead. You're "giving a man a fish" here, not "teaching a man to fish". Explain the problem, explain why your solution fixes it.

Comment: no, it's for everybody reading this page. *I* understand what you've done, but I'm encouraging you to improve your answer so that it is useful to other current and future readers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132687/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya--and-andy-turner).

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ Great , Nice Idea .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are seeing duplicate values in the list right ?
Since reference of selectedBusinessTypeList is changed. Change adapter also by creating new adapter by passing new selectedBusinessTypeList and set that adapter to listview again inside that onClick

Comment: He is already using a HashSet variant with the purpose of removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the code to add values by below lines:

```
businessTypeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        businessTypeObj = clubsList.get(position);

        if (!selectedBusinessTypeList.contains(businessTypeObj)) {
            selectedBusinessTypeList.add(businessTypeObj);
        }
    }
});
```